# Separate MySQL query results by month

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

**The situation**

I have a MySQL Database Table with many dates in it.

Now I need to create a table from this tableentries which should look like this:

```
May        |          |
22.05.2014 | Person 1 | Person 2
23.05.2014 | Person 1 | Person 2

June       |          |
02.06.2014 | Person 1 | Person 2
25.06.2014 | Person 1 | Person 2
```

etc..

**The code**

I am now trying to create a loop through all my query results to do so. And right there I stuck.

I am having something like this:

In the "while" (fetch assoc) loop I have this:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $date = $row['pp_date'];
  $month = date('m', strtotime($date));

  $entryarray = array();

}
```

You can see, that I first save the month of the date into the array. And now I don't know, how to create the array to hold all rows for each month in the array to finally output the result into the table.

Comment: Show your query,you probably need a `GROUP BY day(datecol),month(datecol),YEAR(datecol)`

Comment: why do you need tables for each month? it is possible to select a specific month directly in a query using datepart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your table report is for just one year. If so, you can just use the month as an index key on an array.

```
$table = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $month = date('m', strtotime($row['pp_date']));
  if(!isset($table[$month]))
  {
     $table[$month] = array();
  }

  $table[$month][] = $row; //... add a table row
}
```

You can now echo the `$table` array by iterating over the keys of the array. They will be grouped in the order they were created. So that depends upon your SQL query.

```
foreach($table as $month=>$rows)
{
     echo $month;
     foreach($rows as $row)
     {
        print_r($row);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$entryarray = array();
$stmt="";//you statement here
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                      {   
   $date = $row['pp_date'];
   $month = date('m', strtotime($date));
   $entryarray[$month][] =$row['data1'];//populate your array by the required data indexed by the month
   $entryarray[$month][] =$row['data2'];
   $entryarray[$month][] =$row['data3'];
    }
```

then to get your data you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($entryarray  as $key => $value) {
    print $key; //you will get the key of your array
    foreach ($value as $key => $value){print $value; }//the value of the required key
}
```